# dotnet-isolated Azure Function LogLevel Issues

Tags: .net-core, logging, azure-functions

I'm using **AzureFunctionsVersion-4** in **dotnet-isolated** mode with **dotnet-8**!

I'm using the Default logging provider in dotnet.

I have a problem with logging! the problem is, that I have an HTTP call with **HttpClient** to an external service and there are some logs there like the one below:

```
Executing '[FunctionName]' (Reason='New queue message detected on 'queueName'.', Id=e29a273f-4181-4f59-a523-374639efc066)
Start processing HTTP request GET [Endpoint]
Sending HTTP request GET [Endpoint]
Received HTTP response headers after *ms - 200
End processing HTTP request after *ms - 200
Executed '[FunctionName]' (Succeeded, Id=e29a273f-4181-4f59-a523-374639efc066, Duration=*ms)
```

I did everything to get these logs disabled but did not work!

here are the configurations in host.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "Microsoft": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "batchSize": 5
    }
  }
}
```

and in the appsettings.json:

```
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Warning",
    "FunctionName": "Information"
  }
}
```

I was trying to add `"Function": "Warning"` in **host.json** for the "Executing/Executed" logs but It has disabled all of the other logs in the whole of the function!

here is the function code:

```
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionName.Sample.Functions;

public class TestFunction
{
    private readonly ILogger<TestFunction> _logger;
    private readonly IHttpService _httpService;

    public TestFunction(
        ILogger<TestFunction> logger,
        IHttpService httpService
    )
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _httpService = httpService;
    }

    [Function(nameof(TestFunction))]
    public async Task RunAsync([QueueTrigger("%QueueName%")] byte[] bytes, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        try
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Logs...");

            var result = await _httpService.Call(cancellationToken);

            _logger.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

## program.cs

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
.ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices((builder, services) =>
    {
        // ...

        var configuration = builder.Configuration;

        // ...
    })
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
    {
        builder.ConfigureApp(context); // Add ENV variables here
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

The point here is that the same configuration is working properly in the dotnet-6 project!

Does anyone have any opinion here?

Comment: Mirzael, Can you share your function code?

Comment: @Pavan I updated the question and added the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created Queue trigger function with runtime stack dotnet isolated 8.0.

- I have added the below code in Program.cs, then getting all executed and executing logs. check below:

```cs
.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.Services.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options =>
        {
            LoggerFilterRule defaultRule = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName
                == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");
            if (defaultRule is not null)
            {
                options.Rules.Remove(defaultRule);
            }
        });
    })
```

**Function code:**

```cs
namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            _logger.LogInformation("This is Information log");
            _logger.LogWarning("This is Warning log");
            _logger.LogError("This is Error log");
            _logger.LogCritical("This is Critical log");
            return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
        }
    }
}
```

- Application insights captures only above `Warning` severity level by default. You need to disable it in part of service configuration in program.cs below:

**Program.cs:**

```cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.Services.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options =>
        {
            LoggerFilterRule defaultRule = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName
                == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");
            if (defaultRule is not null)
            {
                options.Rules.Remove(defaultRule);
            }
        });
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

In Isolated function give the logging level for function and default are seperately in host.json. check below:

**Host.json:**

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Function": "Information"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": false, 
        "excludedTypes": "Request" 
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true 
    }
  },
}
```

I have successfully deployed the function into azure portal. Then got triggered and getting logs. check below:

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

- To Refer this [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=windows#managing-log-levels) for isolated model.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the configuration to remove ApplicationInsights Rule! now the problem is here, if you want to remove Executing/Executed logs to have a cleaner log, you need to set "Function" logLevel to "Warning" which in this case we lose all of the Information logs!

Comment: by adding "Function.[MyFunctionName].User": "Information" and "Function": "Warning" worked!